# Server not appearing in Shares for Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, file-sharing

I am trying to create a file share for a server in Active Directory, but I cannot see the server I want to use.

I have two servers, one is Windows Server 2012 R2-GUI and the other is Core. The GUI is my primary AD DS and the DNS Server. The Core is my secondary AD DS and the DHCP Server. As a part of a homework assignment, I have to create three file shares on the Core Server: C:\Public, C:\Instructors, C:\Lessons.

I am using the GUI Server Manager>File and Storage Services to try and create Shares, but my Core Server will not show up. The closest thing I can find is an unreachable version of the server before I renamed and configured it.

I've tried searching the Microsoft Blogs and all over here to see if anyone else has had this problem, but nothing sounds quite the same. If you could help me understand the issue and how to fix it (if possible), I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What roles have you installed on the second server?  I believe you need the **FS-Resource-Manager** role installed on the server for it to show up properly.

Try adding this role.

```
Add-WindowsFeature -Name FS-Resource-Manager
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding the "doing your homework for you" syndrome, perhaps you could google "create Windows share command line" and "create Windows share Powershell".

It can also be done via the GUI from another box (as you seem to be attempting). In that instance, your server must be set up to allow "SM Remoting" (for Server Manager remoting), or WinRM, or Powershell. SConfig is a handy tool. Check firewall rules (some commands for configuring the various remoting methods will configure the firewall for you).

I think it's simpler to try creating the share from the command line first on your core server.

In any case, what happens if you run `net view \\CoreServer` from the other server? Because if it's a domain controller, you should at the very least see the SYSVOL and NETLOGON shares.

Also, I hope that DC (there is no such thing as a "primary" and "secondary" DC in Windows 2012 AD) is also running DNS. All DCs in the domain must run DNS.

I highly recommend doing a `DCDIAG /s CoreServer` to check its health. And doing some Repadmin to ensure your domain is replicating.

Finally, although this is probably not related, turn off UAC on servers: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/2526083/disabling-user-account-control-uac-on-windows-server

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear about the "primary" and "secondary", that was just how I was looking at the setup. I went back and added the DNS role and it cleared up some other minor issues I was having. I didn't have any luck adding the Shares via the GUI, but I went through with PowerShell and just manually shared and set permissions to the drives and folders I wanted. Thanks for your comment, I hadn't even thought to turn off UAC!